# Why it is not needed to decorate a "const char *" with "extern" when sharing it cross multiple files

Tags: c++, constants

While reading C++ books, I learned that to share a const variable/object cross multiple files, we need to define the const variable once in one of the files, and declare it in each source file where it is used. For example,

In file1.cpp, we define a const int variable globally like

```
extern const int ca = 100;
```

In file2.cpp where we use it, we declare this variable like

```
extern const int ca;
```

The above convention makes perfect sense for me. However, when coming to a const char pointer, we don't need to define it using extern, and it can be shared cross multiple files very well. Why does such a thing happen? For example,

In file1.cpp, we define a const char pointer variable globally like

```
const char *cstr = "hello";
```

In file2.cpp where we use it, we declare this variable like

```
extern const char *cstr;
```

To make my question more specific, why can cstr be used in file2.cpp even though it is not decorated with "extern" in file1.cpp?

Many thanks

Comment: I don't think the "extern" has any effect when used like `extern const int ca = 100;`, ca is actually initialized there. Normally, "extern" tells the compiler there is a variable of this type and name defined somewhere; when I link check for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is one of linkage.  When you define a variable at
namespace scope, and there is no previous declaration which
establishes linkage, the linkage external if the object is not
const, internal if it is.  So when you write:

```
int const ca = 100;
```

in a source file, the linkage will be internal, and the entity
(the variable) `ca` refers to will be unique to that translation
unit.  If you'd written:

```
int ca = 100;
```

the linkage would be external, so an

```
extern int ca;
```

in another translation unit would refer to the same variable.

And of course, when you write:

```
char const* cstr = "hello";
```

you are defining a pointer, which isn't const (although it
points to const).

Of course, normally, you'd declare the variables in a header,
with `extern`, so there would be a previous declaration when you
define the variables, and it is the first declaration which
establishes the linkage.

Answer (score 0):

extern is used to make it explicit that the statement "extern const char *cstr;" is a declaration and not a definition, cstr is defined somewhere else. If you did "const char *cstr;" the compiler would interpret that as a definition and you'd end up with 2 cstr variables.

If you apply extern on "const char *cstr = "hello";" I guess the compiler ignores it because the initialization means you actually are defining the variable.

More here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_variable

Comment: But of course, `extern char const* cstr = "abc";` is a definition.  `extern` plays a role in whether something is a definition, or just a declaration, but it's only one element.  Any variable with initialization is a definition (at least at namespace scope---static data members are still declarations, even if they have an initializer).

Comment: And the Wikepedia article you cite is horrible.  The author doesn't know C or C++.  And he seems unaware that many other languages have the concept of an external variable.